# Glightbox problem in mobile horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, lightbox, ng-lightning

I have a problem with the glightbox component, I have more or less managed to work well for me, but in mobile, I don't know what happens that a horizontal scroll is added, making the page not responsive. I have tried everything, I have looked everywhere but I have not been able to make it work, does the same thing happen to someone?
[Glightbox Component](https://github.com/biati-digital/glightbox)

Comment: I am using the glightbox component together with Flickity Carousel

Comment: Please add to your answer what u've tried so far, the code used and maybe a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Solved by magic art, I don't know what it was, I had something that gave me problems, but I have touched something that is already there.